# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't start - missing ATL100.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

After installing Visual Studio 2010 Premium and trying to start it, following error message pops up:
Program can't be started, ATL100.dll is missing. Reinstall program to solve the problem.

I searched for the ATL100.dll and found it in:

- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\redist\ia64\Microsoft.VC100.ATL"
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC100.ATL"
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.ATL"

Copying the file to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE" also won't work.
Any tips how to fix this problem so i can start VS 2010 ?

Comment: Program can't be started, ATL100.dll is missing. **Reinstall program to solve the problem.**

Comment: have you tried "Reinstall program to solve the problem"

Comment: Yes, I reinstalled it. I'm currently trying to "repair" it, let's see if this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'works. I re-reinstalled it and deselected all C++ components during the installation.

Answer (score 1):

If ATL stands for "Active Type Library" then it could be some helper DLL for it. Because ATL also is a COM based framework, it could be necessary to register the DLL. Copying would not work in that case.

```
regsvr32 ATl100.dll
```

Just a hint for the next time.

Answer (score 1):

FYI,

I had same problem.
I couldn't run both Visual Studio 2010 (SP1) and 2012 (U1) due to same error.

I could fix by just repair/reinstalling Visual Studio Service Pack 1.
Here are details.

1. Repair/Reinstall Visual Studio 2010 -> didn't help
2. Reinstall Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 -> fixed the problem of VS2010, but VS2012 still had problem
3. Reinstall Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 -> fixed the problem of VS2012

During no. 3, I couldn't see any GUI. So I just pressed enter key after launch the Update 1 setup.