# ATL100.DLL is missing

Tags: visual-c++, com, atl

I have build COM object to executable. In works fine on my PC. I moved it to another PC and run. Got error:

```
The program can't start because ATL100.DLL is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application needs dependency files redistributed.

- [Visual Studio 2010 not starting - Missing ATL100.DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947868/visual-studio-2010-not-starting-missing-atl100-dll) (second answer)
- [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah(v=vs.100).aspx)